# Select Query Error with Date

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this with these sample data

[image]

I write this query

```
SELECT SUM(amount),DATE(date) FROM outgoings WHERE outgoings_type_id = '1'GROUP BY amount
```

I got the output like this

[image]

I want it not like this but like this(I did some photoshop edit to above one!)

[image]

The only change is I want the summation of amounts which are on same date..Others are normal way..Is it possible or not with some changes to my query..?

Comment: cant you just cut and paste the output from mysql client app command line tool, mysql workbench, sqlyog :)

Comment: sorry.. next time I will do it. GROUP BY date works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you do your sum(amount) and group by date.

`SELECT SUM(amount),DATE(date) FROM outgoings WHERE outgoings_type_id = '1'GROUP BY DATE(date)`

Your aggregate (sum or whatever) will be grouped by the date field then.

Also, I don't think you need to do DATE(date)

`SELECT SUM(amount),date FROM outgoings WHERE outgoings_type_id = '1'GROUP BY date`

Comment: Thanks broo... It works nicely.. I got the theory of Group by perfectly

Comment: np, check the edit, I don't think you need the date function either.

Comment: No it should be DATE(date) like you 1st mentioned..otherwise it won't give expected output